# Name of this famous question?

Tags: geometry

I think that this question is well known but I cannot remember its name, and now I am interested in it and wanted to look it up, but cannot find anything just based on a description. If anyone knows the name or can find it (or anything similar), that would be very helpful. The question is as follows:

> You have a rigid rod of unit length, and some curve in 3d space, which
>   is linear for all but a finite portion of its length. We say the rod
>   is "on the curve" if each of its endpoints are on the curve. Call the
>   "ends of the curve" the 2 linear portions that are infinite. Prove or
>   disprove that for all possible such curves, we can move the rod from
>   one end of the curve to the other while staying on the curve the whole
>   time.

Comment: So the curve is a _single_ infinite line with a middle section cut out and replaced by something else -- or can the two ends of the curve go in independent directions?

Comment: It can go in independent directions, although I think the two would be equivalent, no?

Comment: x @Hardik: A curve that consists of one _narrow_ 180° turn connected to infinite straight rays parallel to each other cannot be navigated by the ladder -- there'll be no way to turn it around.

Comment: Oh yes, youre right. Then I'll require the ends to go in opposite directions.

Comment: A precise condition is stated in Theorem 2 quoted below. The beginning and end segments (which need not be infinite) must be isolated in a sense, a sense violated by Henning's example.

Comment: @HenningMakholm He is not asking you to answer this question. He is merely trying to find its name.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

One name in the literature is: *The Ladder Movers' Problem*:

---

[image: ProbDef]

---

> Goodman, Jacob E., János Pach, and Chee Yap. 
>   "Mountain climbing, ladder moving, and the ring-width of a polygon." 
>   *American Mathematical Monthly* 96.6 (1989): 494-510.
>   ([ACM link](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=71986), [JSTOR link](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2323971).)

---

[image: LadderFig4]

     
<sup>Fig.4 from tech report</sup>

---

[image: Thm2]

---

Comment: Note that requiring the curve to be polygonal rather than just continuous is crucial for the result to hold.

Answer (score 25):

The problem seems to be surprisingly dependent on the precise assumptions we make. Consider, for example, this curve

[image: plot of the curve defined by]
$ \kern-2em\displaystyle \gamma(t) = \begin{cases}
\langle \max(t,-1),t \rangle & t \le 0 \\
\langle t,\frac34 t \sin(5 \log(t)) \rangle & 0 < t \le 1 \\
\langle \cos(t-1)),\sin(t-1) \rangle & 1 \le t \le 1+\pi \\
\langle -1, t-1-\pi \rangle & 1+\pi \le t 
\end{cases} $

This is a **continuous** curve with a Lipschitz continuous parameterization (the derivative of $t\sin(\log(t))$ is bounded) and is therefore **rectifiable**. And the ends are in opposite directions as required.

Yet, the ladder cannot be moved *continuously* along the curve.

Imagine that it moves from high parameter values to low ones. Whenever the front is is at one of the points where the curve touches the *upper* red line ($y=\frac34x$), the *back* end will need to be around point $A$ on the circular arc, since that is the only place on the curve behind the front end that has the right distance from it. ($A$ is the center of the radius-$1$ circle that has $y=\frac34x$ as tangent at the origin).

Conversely, when the front end is at one of the points where the curve touches the *lower* red line, the back end must be around $B$. Since the front oscillates between the two red lines infinitely many times before it reaches the origin, so must the back end oscillate between $A$ and $B$. But that means that **the position of the back end cannot tend to a limit** while the front end approaches $(0,0)$, so a *continuous* movement of the ladder is impossible.

(The factors of $\frac34$ and $5$ are just there to allow the diagram to show enough of the wiggles to make it clear what is going on. It would work just as well with $t\sin(\log t)$ as with $\frac 34t\sin(5\log t)$, only not as visibly. It is important to keep the largest of the wiggles from extending beyond the unit circle, though -- otherwise the argument about where the back end of the ladder *has to be* won't work).

---

Requiring the curve to be (piecewise) smooth will probably avoid this kind of trouble.

Comment: Umm... the OP didn't ask to answer the quoted question. They asked how is that question *called*, not *answered*.

Comment: Still, a cool example illustrating some unintuitive complexities that can occur.  The inverse, what family of curves (continuous or not) can be produced, is probably also interesting.

Comment: It doesn't seem to require that both ends of the rod must move at once. In your example, if the rod's endpoints are initially $(-1,1)$ and $(-1,0)$ we can slide it to endpoints $(-1,0), (0,0),$ and then keep the end $(0,0)$ fixed while rotating the other end along the semi-circle to $(1,0).$  But  the  part of the curve sufficiently close to $(1,0), $ and lying below the $x$-axis,  has slope $>1.$  So when the rod's endpoints are at $(0,0), (0,1)$ we cannot move the  endpoint $(0,0)$ onto the ray $\{(x,x):  x<0\}$ without puling the other end off the curve

Comment: @user254665: The endpoints don't have to move at once, but they do have to keep a distance of exactly one unit at all times. The point is that for this curve you _cannot_ get it into position $(-1,0),(0,0)$ in the first place.

Comment: @user254665: I've tried to make the argument clearer, with some labels on the diagram and a minor bug fixed.

Comment: This is not an answer. You are attempting to answer the question. The op simply wants the question to be identified.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck: That's not a reason to withhold relevant information. In particular, the variant the problem Joseph O'Rourke found a solution for is not exactly the same as the problem the OP described. This answer is to point out that the difference between them is meaningful, such that a reader isn't misled into thinking because the answer to the polynomial variant is "yes", the answer to the general variant is the same.